# How to convert a csv list to a character vector in R

Tags: r

I am new to R.  I have a .csv file with a series of identifiers in a column that look like:

```
F653
F763
F121
F123
...
```

These values are in a vertical column, and I want to import them into R in the format

```
data <- c("F653", "F763", "F121", "F123")
```

I'm sure this is relatively easy but I'm stuck, so any advice would help.

Comment: Please, rephrase your question. It does not make much sense, as you're writing the elements in an array, instead of reading them from the file.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Given a file that only has one column `file_1.csv`, e.g.:

```
F653
F763
F121
F123
```

... it isn't really a CSV file because there are no commas separating the values. Nevertheless, you can read it with `dat1 <- read.csv("file_1.csv",header=F)` to obtain:

```
> dat1
    V1
1 F653
2 F763
3 F121
4 F123
```

Alternatively, a two-column comma-separated file `file.csv`:

```
F653,1
F763,2
F121,3
F123,4
```

... the file can be read in like:

```
> dat <- read.csv("file.csv",header=F)
> dat
    V1 V2
1 F653  1
2 F763  2
3 F121  3
4 F123  4
```

However, `dat` and `dat1` are both data tables. If you want a vector instead of a data table from `file_1.csv`, you can get that like this:

```
> dat <- read.csv("file.csv",header=F)$V1
> dat
[1] F653 F763 F121 F123
Levels: F121 F123 F653 F763
```

You can see that the vector has been read as a factor by default.

If you want a character vector, you can get that from:

```
> as.character(dat)
[1] "F653" "F763" "F121" "F123"
```

Comment: You can also add the `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` Argument to `read.csv` which automatically reads all strings as characters and not factors.

Answer (score 31):

I'd like to add another solution. It provides a  character vector right away.

```
dat = readLines("file.csv")
```